# How to apply query timeout in Community Neo4j JAVA Bolt Driver Api

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

How to apply Transaction timeout in Community Neo4j JAVA Bolt Driver API
I am trying to apply TransactionConfig timeout but it seems to not take effect.

```
session.beginTransaction(TransactionConfig.builder()
                .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
                .build())
```

Is there a way to automatically have threads to timeout after x seconds per query-based.
Community edition Neo4j honours configs

```
dbms.transaction.timeout
dbms.lock.acquisition.timeout
```

But is there a way to set these configs per query/transaction?